# ForEach in SwiftUI swaps the views (and thus re-using them) between Section instead of updating the data and respecting the view modifiers

Tags: ios, foreach, swiftui

```swift
struct MasterView: View {
    @ObservedObject var store: ModelStore

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Black Items")) {
                ForEach(store.bag.blackItems, id: \.self) { item in
                    BlackItemView(model: item)
               }
            }

            Section(header: Text("Blue Items")) {
                ForEach(store.bag.blueItems, id: \.self) { item in
                    BlueItemView(model: item)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { self.store.swapItems() }, label: {
            Text("Swap items")
        }))
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of `swapItems`

```
func swapItems() {
    var bagCopy = bag
    bagCopy.blackItems = bag.blueItems
    bagCopy.blueItems = bag.blackItems
    self.bag = bagCopy
}
```

```
struct Item: Hashable, Identifiable {
   var id: String
}

struct Bag {
    var blackItems: [Item] = [Item(id: "item1")]
    var blueItems: [Item] = [Item(id: "item2")]
}

class ModelStore: ObservableObject {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var bag: Bag = Bag() {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    func swapItems() {
        var bagCopy = bag
        bagCopy.blackItems = bag.blueItems
        bagCopy.blueItems = bag.blackItems
        self.bag = bagCopy
    }
}
```

Launch the application, the color and item names are what they read.

[image: Initial state]

After tapping "Swap items" button, I expect the items to be swapped between sections, but the color of the labels in the sections should remain the same.

The actual result and the expected output is described in screenshot.

[image]

This might be a bug in `ForEach`, but I would like to get a perspective from the community if there is something wrong in my code snippet.

Comment: can you give code of ```ModelStore```, please?

Comment: confirm - for me it looks like a bug too

Answer (score 0):

I did file a bug report to Apple, but in the meanwhile I found a workaround. Not the best one, but it works. The solution is to trick the ForEach that there are new items altogether instead of telling it that the items got swapped. Here is the update to `ForEach`

```
List {
        Section(header: Text("Black Items")) {
            ForEach(store.bag.blackItems, id: \.updatedDate) { item in
                BlackItemView(model: item)
           }
        }

        Section(header: Text("Blue Items")) {
            ForEach(store.bag.blueItems, id: \.updatedDate) { item in
                BlueItemView(model: item)
            }
        }
    }
```

The trick lies at `id` parameter. I updated `Item` to have the second identifier in the form of `updatedDate`. This will have altogether a new value each time I swap items. This forces ForEach to relinquish the views it is holding and recreate the views afresh. Here is change to `Item` structure

```
struct Item: Hashable, Identifiable {
     var id: String
     var updatedDate: Date = Date()
}
```

Here is the change to swapItems function in ModelStore

```
func swapItems() {
    var bagCopy = bag
    bagCopy.blackItems = bag.blueItems.map { item in
        var copy = item
        copy.updatedDate = Date()
        return copy
    }
    bagCopy.blueItems = bag.blackItems.map { item in
        var copy = item
        copy.updatedDate = Date()
        return copy
    }
    self.bag = bagCopy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a direct answer to your situation. Instead of using value enumaration, you can use INDEX. This will guarantee the result is right.

```
  List {
Section(header: Text("Black Items")) {
    ForEach(0..<(store.bag.blackItems.count), id: \.self) { index in
        BlackItemView(model: self.store.bag.blackItems[index])
   }
}

Section(header: Text("Blue Items")) {
    ForEach(0..<(store.bag.blueItems.count), id: \.self) { index in
        BlueItemView(model: self.store.bag.blueItems[index])
    }
}
}
```